# Instrumenting a benign instruction hangs the program

Tags: gcc, assembly, instrumentation, gnu-assembler, dwarf

I'm working on instrumenting a piece of assembly code and I noted the following interesting phenomena:

The original assembly:

```
  64     .loc 1 22 0 is_stmt 0 discriminator 1
  65     cmpl    $31, -4(%rbp)   #, i
  66     jg  .L2 #,
```

Instrumented assembly:

```
  64     .loc 1 22 0 is_stmt 0 discriminator 1
  65     cmpl    $31, -4(%rbp)   #, i
  66     addq    $15, %r15
  67     jg  .L2 #,
```

**First, `r15` is not used by any other part of the assembly (ensured by `gcc --fixed-r15`).**
After adding a single `addq`, the program hangs (like there is a dead loop). I didn't understand what's the significance with that `add` so I tried to put it at other places. Interestingly, I found that whenever it's added after a section with **`discriminator 1`**, then some errors would occur. Any idea? I couldn't fully understand the `discriminator` after a reading of [this](http://wiki.dwarfstd.org/index.php?title=Path_Discriminators). Will keep reading.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

In general you cannot simply *add* instructions into an existing assembly listing and hope everything will work out as before. For example, the added instruction may modify some architectural state that changes the behavior of the following instructions.

In your particular example, the `addq` instruction will overwrite the flags previously set by the prior `cmpl` instruction, so the conditional `jg` will do the wrong thing (looping forever in your case).

Comment: You're exactly right. So I'm in the process of figuring out how to add instructions I need properly. Where can I find information regarding which flags are modified by which? I guess Intel's manual is one...

Comment: The Intel software developers guide is certainly one place, but the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) here on SO has a ton of other good links, including references that are a lot more compact than the 1,000+ page intel guides.

Comment: BTW, the `lea` instruction allows you to add two registers (and more) without modifying the flags.

Comment: will check out. I actually only need to add an immediate value to a register. Is there a good candidate for that?

Comment: `lea` can add immediates also.